# SQL-Statement to calculate time between two days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql database table where want to get all the records between two timestamps. Every time the status changes, I get a new timestamp and new number of `Status`.

Someting like this: Status_List

```
 Status            Time_Start        Time_End
    2               14:00:12          14:13:33
    5               14:13:33          15:33:41
    9               15:33:41          16:02:11
```

When i search:

```
select * from Status_List where Time_Start between (15:00:00 and 16:00:00)
```

```
Output: 9  15:33:41  16:02:11
```

But i need:

```
Output: 5 15:00:00  15:33:41
        9 15:33:41  16:00:00
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You are selecting by `Time_Start` column, there is no `15:00:00` value, So the result  you are getting is correct.

Comment: i know that. But i need the 33:41 mins too for the status

Comment: There are no days here !?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    Status
    ,CAST(GREATEST('15:00:00',Time_Start) AS TIME(0)) as Time_Start
    , Time_end
FROM Status_List
WHERE 
    Time_Start BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '16:00:00'
OR  
    Time_start < '15:00:00' AND Time_End > '15:00:00';
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT 
    -> Status
    -> ,CAST(GREATEST('15:00:00',Time_Start) AS TIME(0)) as Time_Start
    -> , Time_end
    -> FROM Status_List
    -> WHERE 
    -> Time_Start BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '16:00:00'
    -> OR  
    -> Time_start < '15:00:00' AND Time_End > '15:00:00';
+--------+------------+----------+
| Status | Time_Start | Time_end |
+--------+------------+----------+
|      5 | 15:00:00   | 15:33:41 |
|      9 | 15:33:41   | 16:02:11 |
+--------+------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: That would also falsely include a record from 17:00:00 to 18:00:00: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2054af04a5bb5c6087b516d97930b59c

Comment: hi an thanks. This workes creat. I try to calculated the time from 15:00:00 to 15:33:41. so i add: ,CAST(GREATEST('15:00:00',Time_Start) AS TIME(0)) as Time_Start
    -> , Time_end, timediff(Time_end,Time_Start) as timeOfStatus. But for the first time, i get the whole time. Not the time from 15:00:00. any idea for this?

Comment: use this: **timediff(Time_end,GREATEST('15:00:00',Time_Start) ) as timeOfStatus**

Comment: you are awesome ! Thanks

Comment: It works Great.  But i have some trouble with my last row. I see status 3: 19:43 but it should end At 20:00 (bar closed), but i have problems with the time.  I expect 13 minutes, but i get the timediff to the next status in the morning at 07:00. How i can cap the time at a variable time (best case my end_time i search for)

Comment: 19:43 is this the end time . can you post the last 3 rows and say which value is wrong

Comment: Also you can call me to 24:00. me phonenumber is in the profile

Answer (score 1):

With UNION ALL:

```
set @start = '15:00:00', @end = '16:00:00';

select status, @start start, time_end end from status_list
where time_start = 
  (select max(time_start) from status_list where time_start <= @start)
union all
select status, time_start, time_end from status_list
where time_start > @start and time_end < @end 
union all
select status, time_start, @end from status_list
where time_end = 
  (select min(time_end) from status_list where time_end >= @end)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j3GrqNDs4WSHi1vNFgS8E5/1).
Results:

```
| status | start    | end      |
| ------ | -------- | -------- |
| 5      | 15:00:00 | 15:33:41 |
| 9      | 15:33:41 | 16:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right you want to get rows where either the start is in the range or the end. To cut off the values leaving the range you can use a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT status,
       CASE
         WHEN time_start < '15:00:00' THEN
           '15:00:00'
         ELSE
           time_start
       END time_start,
       CASE
         WHEN time_end > '16:00:00' THEN
           '16:00:00'
         ELSE
           time_end
       END time_end
       FROM status_list
       WHERE time_start >= '15:00:00'
             AND time_start < '16:00:00'
              OR time_end >= '15:00:00'
                 AND time_end < '16:00:00';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a7a576e5629e8f0bca23942a3c59abc)

Comment: It is not necessary to test the **time_end** at the last line. the time_end can be grater 16:00 and start_time < 15:00 the only 1 row will give back

Comment: @BerndBuffen: Wouldn't excluding the last expression lead to include a period say from 17:00 to 18:00 then? As 18:00 >= 15:00...